# how to write clean code in c# language and improve quality of code

Tags: c#, coding-style

how i can improve our code quality and write clean code. if i write a unclean ugly code then how i can migrate as a good code (beautiful and clean).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Everyone finds it's own way of what clean code means, BUT there are few things you might want to know, which will help to reach that level/others understand your code (because in this world practically everything have it's own standards).

- Each Class/Method should be responsible just for one thing/task ([OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)).
- **Use best-practices**:

  - [Coding Techniques and Programming Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291596(v=VS.71).aspx),
  - [Design Guidelines, Managed code and the .NET Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/articles/361363.aspx),
  - [Design Guidelines for Class Library Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czefa0ke(vs.71).aspx)
- Comment your code, but not too much, just make it simple to understand.
- Use readable variable names, no more x1s, tempC.. etc...
- Do "big image" optimizations first, others latter.
- Read some open source projects code.
- Use [Unit Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) or in best case [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development).
- Learn and use [Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science)), [C# implementations](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx).

Comment: I really dont agree with code comments, make meaningful method names, they will never age and can be refactored, comments will be left in the dirth when the code is refactored.

Answer (score 3):

1. use stylecop
2. refactor the code
3. rewrite if you can't fix it.
4. most importantly: write good code from the start.

Comment: suggest me how! code is working fine. and suited me good but other person say that it's garbage or ugly code

Comment: Perhaps you should talk to that other person then?

Comment: @Richa: I forgot where I've read it, he say it's hard to know how a beautiful code looks like, but he can easily tell if the code is bad or ugly.  In short, beauty is in the eye of the beholder, just take your colleague's criticism with a grain of salt.  And it's easy to judge if something is bad or ugly, especially if the style of coding doesn't conform to another person's style

Comment: or Ask that person! don't vent here or to Femaref, perhaps you should channel your frustration to that other person

Comment: Case in point about judging that a certain code is beautiful is harder http://www.equivalence.co.uk/archives/101.  On first code, you can not easily decide if the suggested code is beautiful, because you might have a preference that a function should have only one exit point.  But you can easily decide that the original code is downright ugly

Comment: i am not richa i am anirugdha nick name aniru don't say @ Richa.

Comment: @aniru, how can we know, we don't have clairvoyance power to infer that there is a nickname aniru lurking in name `Richa Media and services`, much less anirugdha :-)

Answer (score 2):

Don't write code unless you failing have a test

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development

Answer (score 2):

Read Robert Martin's [Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)

Yes, I know 'Java', but it really is a very good book.

Answer (score 1):

Use [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx) and read [Framework design Guidleines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613).

Answer (score 0):

There are standards of writing the code read more about Design Engineering (talks about abstraction, architecture, patterns ... etc), 
if you already have a spaghetti code Never Ever Ever Rewrite it. the golden rule is if it is not broken don't fix it. you have to design the interfaces and reshape the classes and just move the code carefully and test it. and to make clean code you need to make standard coding practices like naming conventions (as example) and follow the coding practices and standards at start of a project.

Answer (score 0):

Read a book like cleancode,implementation patterns.They help a lot in understanding how to write clean code

Answer (score 0):

It requires lot of effors and knowledge to accomplish what you have mentioned.

Robert C Martin's Clean Code would be an ideal way to start.

Martin Fowler's Refactoring also a wise option.

Read [my blog](http://sweettam.blogspot.com/2011/07/journey-towards-software-craftsmanship.html) on this topic.

You can find lot of good articles on this topic [here](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/codeArticles.html).